# Delete xml files older than 4 weeks from different locations with same foldername XML using bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I have this line but I need it to run ONLY on XML folders and sub-folders under `/home/user` location:

```
find /home/user "*.xml" -type f -name +4 -exec rm -f {}\;
```

Comment: what is XML folder? Folder containing XML files?

Comment: You should also re-post the command you are using, since the one you have now/before first edit clearly got chopped in translation.

Comment: The XML folder has files included.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Find the folders "XML" first, then delete xml files.

```
find /home/user -type d -name "XML" |while read folder
do
  find ${folder} -type f -name "*.xml" -mtime +28 -exec rm -f {} \;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find /home/user -regex ".*/XML/.*\.xml" -type f -mtime +28 -exec rm -f {} \;
```